# Should I set two model for Devise gem for a freelancer vs someone hiring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm working on a freelance site where there will be people looking to hire freelancers and freelancers looking for work. The homepage will display a list of freelancers in which users can click to view their profile.

I was wondering if it will be better to generate a Devise model for both freelancer and users or should I just generate one for User and then use a gem like Cancan to set authorization levels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have one User model with user type (freelancer vs client) and handle your authorization based on that.

Comment: What do you mean by User type?

Comment: A string attribute on the model, called Type. So, for example, you can do this when generating the model: `rails g model User name:string email:string type:string`. This lets you have additional user types as well, such as admin, for which you can use for authorization of admin-level tasks.